# karma parallel executing test cases twice

Tags: angular, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am upgrading my angular from 4 to version 7. I had karma-parallel to run the tdd and it was working as expected with Angular 4. Now after upgrading to 7 the same tests are running twice before stop executing.
My karma.conf.js is as below,

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: [ 'parallel', 'jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-parallel'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    parallelOptions: {
      executors: 3, // For Jenkins enterprise, stick to 6 executors. For local laptop, change to 3-5
      shardStrategy: 'round-robin'
    },
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      },
      clearContext: false
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'json', 'text-summary'],
      dir: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },    
    reporters: ['spec', 'kjhtml'],
    specReporter: {
         maxLogLines: 5,
         suppressErrorSummary: true,
         suppressFailed: false,
         suppressPassed: false,
         suppressSkipped: true,
         showSpecTiming: true,
         failFast: false
      },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
            base: 'ChromeHeadless',
            flags: [
                '--no-sandbox', // required to run without privileges in docker
                '--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-test-profile',
                '--disable-web-security',
                '--no-proxy=http://0.0.0.0:9876/'
            ]
        }
    },
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity,
    captureTimeout: 180000,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 90000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 180000
  });
};
```

The command used to run the test cases is as below,

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --source-map=false
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `ng test` it will run the tests for *all* projects.

For instance, if you have these two projects in your `angular.json`:

- `hello-world` (with 10 tests)
- `utilities` (with 100 tests)

then when you run `ng test` it will run tests for both `hello-world` and `utilities`.

**However if you are using Karma with watch files or auto-watch enabled**, it will stop at the first project so you will only see 10 tests run (or 100 tests depending on the order of the projects). Then when you Ctrl+C and exit the Karma process, it will continue to the next project, compile it and run the tests. So you will have *two* test runs.

### What to do?

- If you have multiple Angular applications but are deploying *one* to production you should use `ng test <app>` with the project name that you are deploying.
- If you have an Angular application and a *library* you will want to test the application and the library: `ng test <app> && ng test <library>`
- If you want to run the full test suite, just do `ng test` and don't forget to change Karma to run a single test run and not to auto-watch for changed files!
- Update the `karma.conf.js` for each project to ensure it has the correct settings (no watching, single run, correct browsers to use)

Answer (score 1):

So I have found the issue. In **angular.json** file i have 2 projects both have the test block configured and that was causing it to run twice. Removing the last project test block resolved it. Not sure how Angular 4 was running the TDD only once while with the same configuration Angular 7 run it twice.

Comment: It's strange that this happens at all because when you run angular commands they should be using the `defaultProject`

Comment: @RudolfOlah. yes similar to how ng serve only runs default/first site